# Apollo gateway - custom resolver (translate graphql to rest)

Tags: rest, graphql, apollo

I have an apollo gateway working fine. It creates a supergraphsdl and federates all the requests to underlying services (graphql as well).

However,
I have a REST service (3rd party) which I need to connect via API GW (Apollo) and thus I need a way how to translate incoming GQL requests to that specific schema to REST requests.

My ApolloServer:

```
ApolloServer({
    gateway,
    context: createContext,
    introspection: true,
    debug: true,
    formatError: globalErrorFormatter,
  });
```

and my ApolloGateway:

```
ApolloGateway({
    supergraphSdl: createSuperGraphSdl(serviceSourceMap),
    buildService: ({ url, name }) => {
      const schema = backingSchemas.get(name);
      const isRestService = name.includes("rest");
      if (schema == null) {
        throw new Error(`Missing backing service config for serviceName=${name}`);
      }
      const localGQLDataSource = isRestService ? new CustomDataSource(schema) : new LocalGraphQLDataSource(schema);
      return localGQLDataSource;
    },
  });
```

here is my CustomDataSource

```
class CustomDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
  willSendRequest({ request }: any): string {
    const serviceUrl = request?.http?.url;
    const queryContent = request.query;
    console.log("----CUSTOM REQUEST:", queryContent);
    console.log("SERVICE URL:", serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

I can see the queries going in this class... but there is no way I can stop them here and redirect on my on (willSendRequest) doesn't support returns ....

The catch is, we have a specific setup (custom implementation) for supergraph for by default it doesn't support directives (which we are using to authorize, inject, ...)

Any idea what am I missing? or am I going totally wrong direction??

What I need is to capture GQL query/mutatio and redirect it manually as a POST request to given service.

So let's say:

```
mutation {
  login(username: String!, password: String!): String! @unsecured
}
```

I need to transform that to

axios.post(<service_host>, payload);

any idea? could you guys direct me somewhere or give me a piece of code I can work with? Ideally codepen or smth ...  unfortunately I cannot share the entire gateway code :( but if you need me to provide more/other details .. pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

This mapping of GraphQL to REST will happen in your resolver code.

```
const login = async ( _, { username, password }, context ) => {
  // set up your payload
  const result = await axios.post(host,payload);
  // do more stuff, like creating a jwt or throwing an error for invalid login
  return theString; // whatever result is expected
}
```

Your `login` function needs to be included in your `resolvers` when you create the schema that this particular GraphQL server is built with.

Comment: yeah I kinda already figured a solution which is working great with `apollo-datasource-rest`... .however, I have to figure out now how to combine params of "gateway" + "typeDefs" + "resolvers" + dataSources togher in ApolloServer constructor ... because it seems I cannot have gateway + typeDef and resolvers together ... either the first or the latter .. which sux ... so I gotta figure out now how to inject my custom resolvers and typeDefs into the gateway

Comment: This resolver just needs to be part of *one* of the federated schemas.

Comment: how do I inject it into the gateway? instead of using it as a param (typeDefs, resolvers, dataSources) for the ApolloGateway .... could you share a draft pls?

bec I am getting: "Cannot define both `gateway` and any of: `modules`, `schema`, `typeDefs`, or `resolvers`"

Comment: You don't, it needs to be part of one of your *backingSchema*s

Comment: is there any example I can check and get inspired? I am kinda lost :( thx